# Django join unmanaged tables

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have a four models which each contains their own data. The models are:

- Category (contains department_id foreign key)
- Department (contains data, no foreign key)
- ProductCategory (join table containing only product_id and category_id)
- Product (contains data with no foreign key)

```
# models.py (excluded the rest for brevity)

from django.db import models

class Department(models.Model):
    department_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'department'


class Category(models.Model):
    category_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    #department_id = models.IntegerField()
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'category'

class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    discounted_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    image_2 = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    display = models.SmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'product'

class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'product_category'
        unique_together = (('product', 'category'),)
```

From my endpoint, I need to get all products in a department and return the response in the following format:

```
​"rows"​: [
    {
​      "product_id"​: ​integer​,
      "name"​: ​string​,
      ​"description"​: ​string​,
      "price"​: ​string​,
      ​"discounted_price"​: ​string​,
      "thumbnail"​: ​string​
    }
]
```

This is the endpoint:

`path('products/inDepartment/<int:department_id>/', ProductViewSet.as_view({"get": "get_products_by_department"}))`

How can I go about doing this? I'm stuck with the code below:

```
# products.py

def get_products_by_department(self, request, department_id):
        """
        Get a list of Products of Departments
        """
        categories = Category.objects.filter(department_id=department_id).values('category_id')

        for item in categories:
          category_id = item['category_id']
          products = ProductCategory.objects.filter(category_id=category_id).values(
            'product_id', name=F('product__name'), description=F('product__description'),
          price=F('product__price'), discounted_price=F('product__discounted_price'), thumbnail=F('product__thumbnail'))

        # Return response
        if products.exists():
          return Response(products, 200)
        else:
          return Response(products, 204)
```

The code above works and gives me the correct response but I'm not sure if I'm doing the query correctly? Should I be using a loop or is there a Django way to do it better without a loop?

Answer (score -1):

Django's ORM allows for reverse relationship lookup.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

```
categories = Category.objects.filter(department_id=department_id)    
products = Product.objects.filter(productcategory__category__in=categories)
```